# How to solve $x^\sqrt x=\frac{3x}{2}$?

Tags: logarithms

If  $x^\sqrt x=\frac{3x}{2}$ then how to solve it?
I have tried by taking $\log$ in both side but couldn't reach a solution. Do you have any logarithmic or any other solution?

Comment: By inspection, we can see that $\dfrac{9}{4}$ is one solution. You might be stuck with numerical methods to find the other.

Answer (score 2):

Try this substitution:

Let $y = \sqrt{x}$.

Then $y^{2} = x$, and so, the original equation transforms to

$(y^{2})^y = \frac{3y^{2}}{2}$,

which, after some algebraic manipulation, yields

$y^{2y - 2} = \frac{3}{2}$;

Upon inspection, we see that $y = \frac{3}{2}$;

Whence---

$x = \frac{9}{4}$.

Comment: good step that of substituting (+1) : now at the second line we could try and take the log, maybe we get a step ahead ..

Comment: @G Cab Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that; I recall that it allowed me to explicitly derive $y =\frac{3}{2}$ and so  $x=\frac{9}{4}$; but not, unfortunately, the more interesting solution. Thanks again.

Comment: can you explain if y^(2y-2)=3/2 then how y=3/2?

Comment: substitute in $y=3/2$ for both values of $y$ on the LHS and you get $3/2$ which equals the RHS

Answer (score 0):

Using Mathematica, by inspection there are two solutions. (There are no solutions for $x \geq 3$, because $x^\sqrt{x}$ grows much faster than $\frac{3}{2}x$. This is something you can prove, even though it might not be possible to solve for the roots.)

[image]

They look to be about 0.4 and 2.2, so using `FindRoot` with these guesses gives $\frac{9}{4}$ (as the above commenter said) and $0.361634$. By WolframAlpha, the latter solution does not have an obvious closed form.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the correct ways to solve such an equation is to use a numerical iterative method such as [Bisection Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) or [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). The bisection method may be easier to use since the derivative required by the later method is rather unfriendly.